# Can I include a file into my include file in node.js?

Tags: javascript

I have this in a file page.js

```
var Page = function () {
    this.examStatus = element(by.id('examStatusSelect'));
    this.examType = element(by.id('examTypeSelect'));
}
module.exports = new Page();
```

and this in file admin.js

```
var Admin = function () {
    this.newButton = element(by.id('newButton'));
    this.saveButton = element(by.id('saveButton'));
}
module.exports = new Admin();
```

Is there a way that I could do something like this in the page.js file

```
var admin = require('./admin.js');
```

so as to bring in the items contained in admin.js and make them available as part of the Page function so that I effectively have four properties in the Page function instead of two?

I know I can bring in elements but can I have them appear just like those in admin.js so that I can do:

```
page.examStatus
page.examType
page.newButton
page.saveButton
```

From a script that uses page.js ?

Comment: Admin should be a mixin of page, or it should inherit? This has nothing to do with requires / includes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like either Page needs to inherit from Admin, or vice versa (if "Admin" is-a "Page"), possibly as a mixin.  Unless the properties of Admin need to be static, but this does not sound like what you want. This has nothing to do with requires or including files, just vanilla Javascript inheritance.

Comment: I am not sure how I can do the inheritance howevr and I don't know what a mixin is.

Comment: @SamanthaJ then research those things? I'm just saying file "including" is not the issue.

Comment: @SamanthaJ by research I mean start by googling "mixin" or "javascript mixin." I'm fully aware you don't know what one is given your question, but it's such an easy-to-google term I don't really need to write up more about it. There's *plenty* of guides on inheritance in javascript, so you don't need someone to write a brand new explanation of that either.